# Passing formula through function to cor.test

Tags: r

Take random data and these two functions.

```
data = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,5), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,5))

test_fun1 <- function(data, formula){ lm( formula = formula, data = data)  }
test_fun2 <- function(data, formula){ cor.test( formula = formula, data = data) }
```

`lm` works as expected.

```
test_fun1( data = data, formula= x~y )
```

But I cannot do the same with `cor.test`. This fails:

`test_fun2(data = data, formula= ~x+y)`

Directly it works just fine:

`cor.test( formula = ~x+y, data = data)`

From what I read there could be some scoping problems.
It cannot find the formula passed. The error is "Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" But that is because `formula` cannot be found and it then tries to use the function named `formula`.

How do I make it find the passed function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely a bug in the function.  Try this workaround:

```
test_fun3 <- function(data, formula) { 
  eval.parent(substitute(cor.test( formula = formula, data = data))) 
}
```

This will substitute the arguments to `test_fun3` in and then run it in the parent frame, i.e. that of the caller of `test_fun3`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
test_fun2 <- function(data, formula) { 
     environment(formula) <- environment()
     cor.test(formula = formula, data = data) 
}

test_fun2(data = data, formula= ~x+y)

#         Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  x and y
# t = 1.7596, df = 4, p-value = 0.1533
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.3255130  0.9583575
# sample estimates:
#       cor 
# 0.6605476
```

Comment: There is some question on how cor.test is supposed to work since ?cor.test does not really say but if it is supposed to work like lm then note that lm will look for variables in the formula's environment if it can't otherwise find them and in that case clobbering that environment will not work.  For common cases this should work though.

Comment: Here is an example where `test_fun4` is the version that clobbers the environment.  `fo <- ~ X + Y; environment(fo) <- new.env(); environment(fo)$Y <- 1:5; dd <- data.frame(X = 1:5); test_fun(data = dd, formula = fo)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck OK, I understand the point. Thank you a lot for your important clarification.

Comment: I will upvote the answer because it should work in common cases, cor.test does not really define how it is supposed to work in its help file and it is a simple solution.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you. I appreciate.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the `env` argument in `as.formula` which didn't work.